# Using HTML to reference font name in MS Access report

Tags: html, css, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a rich text, text box in a MS Access report that contains a paragraph and I would like to change the font of just a few words. The font name has a space in it and I can't seem to figure out how to get around it. It works fine with font names that don't have spaces.

```
="<font face=Lucida Handwriting>Kim Anderson</font>"
```

I've tried quoting, single quoting, hyphenating, and parentheses, but maybe I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dd you try doubling up the quotes which is VBA's way to escape quotes

`="<font face=""Lucida Handwriting"">Kim Anderson</font>"`

Comment: Yep, works great! Annoying that single quote didn't do the same.